# How to setup Binding redirect with Nunit's gui runner?

Tags: nunit, .net-4.0, testdriven.net

I am trying to run my unit tests with nHibernate 3 and fluentnHibernate,  To do this I need to  setup a assembly binding redirect so fluentnHibernate will work with the new version of nHibernate.  I have tried to update my test project's app.config however the testdriven.net runner and the nunit gui runner don't seem to read these settings.

below is my test.dll's app.config.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- Others sections -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=SQL2008, 1080;Initial Catalog=TestCOM;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="GeneralLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="GeneralLog"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <qualifyAssembly
          partialName="System.Data.SqlServerCe"
          fullName="System.Data.SqlServerCe, 
Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate"
                          publicKeyToken="AA95F207798DFDB4"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.1001"
                         newVersion="3.0.0.1001"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

I am getting the following error:

TestCase 'FieldGuideTests.Service.SchemaFacts.Can_Build_SQL_Schema'
failed: System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    at FieldGuideService.SessionFactoryManagers.SQL_SessionFactoryManager.CreateSessionFactory()

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=9